# Slow WiFi and disconnections after updating Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04

After updating and restarting my computer (running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) today, internet connection has been really unstable and slow, with frequent disconnections. Here's the list of changes from the history.log

```
Start-Date: 2023-04-28  12:24:07
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.128'
Install: linux-modules-5.15.0-71-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-71.78, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-71-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-71.78, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-71-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-71.78, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-71:amd64 (5.15.0-71.78, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-71.78, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.70.68, 5.15.0.71.69), tzdata:amd64 (2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0, 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), linux-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.70.68, 5.15.0.71.69), libssl3:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9), libssl3:i386 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9), tableplus:amd64 (0.1.212, 0.1.214), ipp-usb:amd64 (0.9.20-1, 0.9.20-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), libssl-dev:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.70.68, 5.15.0.71.69), ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (27.13.6~22.04.1, 27.14.4~22.04), openssl:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.9), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-70.77, 5.15.0-71.78)
End-Date: 2023-04-28  12:25:41

Start-Date: 2023-04-28  13:12:41
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.128'
Remove: linux-modules-5.15.0-69-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-69.76), linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-69-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-69.76), linux-headers-5.15.0-69:amd64 (5.15.0-69.76), linux-image-5.15.0-69-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-69.76), linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-69.76)
End-Date: 2023-04-28  13:12:45
```

And here's the output from `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 14:cb:19:72:e3:f2
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-71-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1304000-b1304fff memory:b1300000-b1303fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 64:6c:80:ca:8b:35
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.15.0-71-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.183.218 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:134 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b120ffff
```

I would be very thankful if anyone could provide some help. Sorry if I made a mistake, English is not my first language.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep 8821` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I too have experienced some instability with my wifi connection. In my research of the issue, some have suggested disabling the powersave option in the NetworkManager configuration.

This is done by editing the `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` file, and changing the line `wifi.powersave=3` to `wifi.powersave=2`.

I'm currently trying this, and though not perfect, it seems to be better than before.

see for reference: [How to turn off wireless power management permanently | Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for offering help, I managed to solve my problem.

After some research I managed to fix it by blacklisting rtw88_8821ce in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and rebooting. This forced the computer to use the already installed rtl8821ce driver instead and now it works fine.